# Serializing Objectify Keys using Gson

Tags: json, google-app-engine, gson, objectify

Has anyone been able to serialize/deserialize objects using gson which have Key (the objectify ones) fields?

I'm trying to use gson to do so but it seems several people online have had issues serializing appengine keys. Any tips?

When I attempt to do so I get the following error on deserialization:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeTranslator$ReferenceType.setPropertyValue(DataTypeTranslator.java:680)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeTranslator.createPropertyValue(DataTypeTranslator.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeTranslator.createProperty(DataTypeTranslator.java:191)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeTranslator.addProperty(DataTypeTranslator.java:159)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeTranslator.addPropertiesToPb(DataTypeTranslator.java:142)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityTranslator.convertToPb(EntityTranslator.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchPutBySize(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:475)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:446)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.AsyncObjectifyImpl.put(AsyncObjectifyImpl.java:255)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.AsyncObjectifyImpl.put(AsyncObjectifyImpl.java:229)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ObjectifyImpl.put(ObjectifyImpl.java:126)
    at com.rewardly.mailfoo.dataaccess.DAO.storeEntity(DAO.java:36)
    at com.rewardly.mailfoo.ajaxcalls.UpdateEntity.doPost(UpdateEntity.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.rewardly.mailfoo.utils.UserFilter.doFilter(UserFilter.java:44)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: It's help to see com.rewardly.mailfoo.ajaxcalls.UpdateEntity.doPost and the the JSON fragement that it's handling.

Comment: Not sure if it can be done (hopefully others can suggest workarounds), but if not, you may check out Jackson instead. A few users have worked on getting Objectify keys working (I assume with success, should be easy to verify).

Answer (score 2):

I have it done as part of the backup suite in one my project. It definitely WORKS for me now.

Try specialization of Gson (de)serializer object by its builder:

```
/** Helper class for deserialization of Key
  * @copyright TrashOut, s.r.o. 2012 */
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 public static class KeyAdapterSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Key>, JsonDeserializer<Key>, InstanceCreator<Key>  {
   @Override
   public JsonElement serialize(Key key, Type type, JsonSerializationContext serialContext) {
     return new JsonPrimitive(key.getString());
   }
   @Override
   public Key deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
       JsonDeserializationContext deserialContext) throws JsonParseException {
     Misc.log.warning(" element content " + element.getAsString());
     return Key.create(element.getAsString());
   }
   @Override
   public Key createInstance(Type type) {
     Misc.log.warning(" element content " + type.getClass());
     return Key.create(BlahBlah.class, 1L);
 /* FIXME: BlahBlah is ANY class storable by your Objectify = registred in DAO
 * (extending DAOBase; registered by OjectifyService.register(clazz) method) ;
 * This MUST return any existing Key -that class has NO nullary constructor; we
 * will change the key immediately after in deserialize method */
   }
 }
```

Final usage in code:

```
public static Gson gson = (new GsonBuilder()).serializeNulls()
.setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapter(Key.class, new KeyAdapterSerializer()).create();
// creating Gson instance which will serialize all and prints nicely
// --> turn off setPrettyPrinting() for performance improvement
// see http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html
// for more preferences

String myObjectJsonStringRepresentation =gson.toJson(myObject);
// in String you have string representation of the all object -WITH THE KEY
```

For completeness:

1. In the Key object there is serialized also GAE application
   identificator. But it can be changed by reflection after key
   retrieval in deserialization method, if needed. It may be required
   when moving the data from the 1st GAE app to another one. For me,
   the app identificator in keys are null right now. If not for you,
   contact me. I will publish appropriate code.
2. This code works for older Gson also. If using 2.1, the TypeAdapter
       subclassing would be better & faster way. It is quite similar to
       this code and you need to implement 2 methods. But this solution
       just works with also older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by simply using Objectify's built-in `DAOBase.fact().stringToKey()` and `DAOBase.fact().keyToString()` methods.

```
String serializedKey = new DAO().fact().keyToString(entity.getKey());
      ...
Key<Entity> entityKey = new DAO().fact().stringToKey(serializedKey);
```

My own problems arose from having to compile under Java 6, because I had been using `Key<?> entityKey = new DAO().fact().stringToKey(serializedKey)`, which was solved by simply changing the type from `<?>` to `<Entity>`.

If, however, you need to serialize the raw low-level Key objects, the methods mentioned in the above answer are now located in KeyFactory instead of on Key. You will still have trouble because AppIdNamespace is transient, private, and there are no methods to set those fields on the key post-deserialization.